# CM3 both cameras recognized but stereo not working

Tags: compute-module-3

I recently started to work with the CM3. When I start raspbian, I can check that both cameras are detected and supported. In addition, I can acquire an image/a video from each separately easily but I can not acquire a stereo image with the 3d flag of raspistill/raspivid. Only one camera is displayed. If I force one or the other with the C's flag, I only see one of the images but never the two combined...

Edit:
I am using the pi noir V2. I realized that my problem came from a misunderstanding/misuse of the command raspivid. I am able to record in stereo (if I read the recorded file in vlc, I see both cameras), it is just that the preview shows only one camera, never the "stereo" view. Is it normal?

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Pierre

Comment: Welcome @user1273813, could you please provide us with the camera's name and model? Also, if you're following a tutorial, can you add the link to it so that we can better understand the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same thing today when setting up a CM with the StereoPi hardware.  Actually it *did* work - it just did not display the two cameras while recording.  Output to a file and view the file, you'll see both images.  For still pictures, try something like `raspistill -n -t 1 -3d sbs -cs 1 -vf -hf -w 5184 -h 1944 -o image.jpg;sudo fbi --autozoom --noverbose --vt 1 image.jpg` after installing fbi. Use -vt 2 if you're using the GUI rather than the console.

Answer (score 2):

Actually raspivid, raspistill etc. can not show stereoscopic *preview*, but can save stereo images and video. RPi engineer 6by9 told me, that Raspberry expects 3D monitor (or TV) to show this preview (discussion is [here](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/554#issuecomment-478060341)). 
But we were needed this option, so we modified sources of raspivid to add 3D preview on a 2D screens. If you need it, you can extract this binary from our SLP Raspbian image (download it from our [Wiki](https://wiki.stereopi.com), bottom-right part, "Downloads" section). Binary is sitting here: /opt/StereoPi/bin/raspivid. It works as a stock raspivid, but if you add '-fs' key (means 'force stereo'), you'll get stereoscopic preview.

Comment: I saw your answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108634) and then found this answer. This is really intriguing, I didn't know there was a two camera Pi. I may write up a question in a few days, trying to decide if one regular Pi just triggering the other by GPIO is good enough for me (3D photography at only a few frames per second of things that change relatively slowly).