# How to use 2 (multiple) cameras in raspberry pi and detect objects and depth mapping

Tags: camera

I am new in raspberry pi and all the hardware stuff and experienced a bit in java.
I have a project which I need to complete pretty soon.

For it, I need to run multiple cameras to cover all four sides and one for up.
That means a minimum of 2 cameras. After it, I need to detect objects using TensorFlow Lite which I know how to do in python and relatively low FPS like 4 FPS is acceptable but not below that. and then I need to get the distance of the detected object from the camera.

It is complex to read I think and a lot for me to do.
Please guide me into what should I use for this and is Raspberry Pi fine for it.
Please also tell me which module and Pi should I buy.

Edit: Overall, what I want to do is detect objects and get the depth map of the detected object. The detected object will be detected by a custom TensorFlow Lite model. Then I need to figure out how far that object is and do some more processing on the distance value. It should be around 4 - 5 FPS minimum. I don't need to show the recording. The problem is that raspberry pi has only 1 camera port but I need to use at least 2. Please Help

Thank You,
with Regards.

Comment: Hello and welcome to this community. Add more information clearly about what are you looking for.

Comment: I will try adding more information

Comment: Please check the question again. I have added more explanation and figured out I need at least 2, not 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that you are going to do is really interesting for me. However, you are right. The Raspberry Pi has only one camera port. It means that you are able to plug only one camera module. Although, you can connect any normal USB camera to this board.

[fosa USB Camera for Raspberry Pi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DDFBZW9) can be a good option for you. It needs no driver and it's easy to use if you want to plug it on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The problem has not gone yet. Can you guide to an alternate board like RPi or some driver? I think that if I use Arduino to use the cameras and then transfer data to the RPi. Is it practical?

Comment: You can attach both cameras to a single board like Raspberry Pi. So, why do you need an alternate board? I didn't get it.

Comment: That is the question that how can I attach both cameras to a single board. Maybe I didn't clarify the question properly

Comment: You mean, in software sight? In the hardware sight, it's not complicated.

Comment: Yes actually if I can plug in the USB cameras but how can I use both cameras simultaneously

Comment: I have accepted because I get the answer on how to connect more than 1 camera to RPi. The software part should be fairly easy I hope.

Comment: It's not important to concern about that. It's like you are concern about how to use a USB mouse and a USB keyboard simultaneously.

Comment: Actually each camera device you'll plug, you can find in `/dev/video0`. If you are worried about that, search `how to use two webcams at once linux` on google.

Comment: I think [link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/) will help me in the software part and they also suggest the same suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103177/discussion-between-demon-app-programmer-and-m-rostami).

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use a [StereoPi](http://stereopi.com/) board, as it allows you to connect two cameras at once. This board is based on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3, so you can work with it as with a classic Raspberry Pi (and use stock Raspbian). I'm one of the developers of this board, so will be glad to help you with all I know.

Your idea of using Tensor Flow light is very interesting!